# Bad Results from Port Check Sites

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port

I'm not a network expert, though I know how to set up a static IP and forward ports. I've always wondered how port checking sites like http://ping.eu/port-chk/ work, because whenever I try them on open ports on my computer they always tell me they don't have access. However, hosting a server from them still works fine, and people outside my network can connect. I've always wondered why this is; whether or not I'm incorrectly forwarding my ports, if I'm looking at the information from the site wrong, or just using the site incorrectly to begin with. If anybody can, please shed some light.